# How to pass params to custom function in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I registered custom function to use Postgresql `to_tsvector`. It has standard name `fts`.
It works as expected but I can't pass params to it. I get:

```
The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.
```

And when I check what param my function get, it is just "?" - without the word I deliver.
Obviously I tried this way:

```
em.createQuery("select c from collections c where fts(c.title, :title) = true", Collection.class)
                .setParameter("title", title);
```

...also with unwrap, I tried to replace `:title` with ? or ?1 etc.
I also tried use `CriteriaBuilder` - with the same bad result.

I did my function according to [this](https://www.zymr.com/postgresql-full-text-searchfts-hibernate/)
Registered my function like this:

```
   public CustomHibernateDialect(){
        super();
        registerFunction("fts", new PgFullTextFunction());
        registerFunction("ts_rank", new StandardSQLFunction("ts_rank", DoubleType.INSTANCE));
        registerFunction("to_tsquery", new StandardSQLFunction("to_tsquery", ObjectType.INSTANCE));
    }
```

In debug mode, I can see that when it comes to `render` function that i overrided, it get only first argument (field that has to be searched), the second argument is just `"?"`.

Comment: Could you please show signature of your custom function (sql definition).

Comment: @SternK I edited my question to add more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like register order has meaning. I change registration order to:

```
   public CustomHibernateDialect(){
        super();
        //order is important here
        registerFunction("to_tsquery", new StandardSQLFunction("to_tsquery", ObjectType.INSTANCE));
        registerFunction("ts_rank", new StandardSQLFunction("ts_rank", DoubleType.INSTANCE));
        registerFunction("fts", new PgFullTextFunction());
    }
```

and now it works as expected. Params are delivered!